# Android fragment is not updating

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a TextView into a fragment. When i update the text property from the activity, the component is not updated on fragment.

```
TextView amountTag = (TextView) fm.findFragmentByTag("currentFrag").getView().findViewById(R.id.amountTag);
amountTag.setText("another text");
```

`fm` variable is my `FragmentManager`.

I already tried to detach and attach the fragment again. But it does not work.

Comment: Have you considered storing a reference to the TextView within the Fragment class. Then write a method within the Fragment class which will update your text view and call that from your Activity instead?

Comment: Are you trying to call this on Activity? onCreate? Or in what LifeCycle of the Activity?

Comment: @Ayzen: I'm trying to call on Activity on event "onNewIntent" (reading a NFC tag).

Comment: @bdavies6086 Yes, I did it. But i had the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you inflate your view in `onCreateView` of your fragment like this:

```
TextView amountTag;

@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
    amountTag= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.amountTag);
    return v; 
}
```

If you have any issue create `setAmountText` in your fragment

```
public void setAmountText(String text) {
   amountTag.setText(text); 
}
```

An call it in your Activity

```
((CurrentFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag("currentFrag")).setAmountText("newValue");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Same problem @g2o. The TextView was not update after call setAmountText.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to problem here:

[Handling onNewIntent in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456873/handling-onnewintent-in-fragment)

The solution is send params to fragment, like:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("amount", "newValue");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

In the fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    amountTag.setText(bundle.getString("amount", "defaultValue"));
}
```

Thanks to everyone that helped!